# Custom language reformatter for notepad++

Tags: programming-languages, notepad++, formatter

I'm a developer for a database platform that uses a specific programming language very similar to `vbscript` to carry out some of the functionality of the user interface. The current developing editor used is `notepad++` which already has a custom language highlighter. The need for a code tidier has emerged and I have already been looking into customizing an already existing formatter/beautifier but have failed to find any proper documentation as how to carry it out properly. As far as i understand, i will probably need to write an interpreter and use `nppexec` plugin, I have written a lexer in bison before so i guess i am not a total beginner.

Can anyone perhaps point out a guide or give a few pointers to make things a bit easier to carry out?